# How to remove php extension only using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Can anyone solve my problem ? I want to remove .php extention only:
My current url is:

`www.example.com/department.php/beakers.html?id=213863`

And I want like this:

`www.example.com/department/beakers.html?id=213863`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What _problem_? You only stated what you _want_, not what actual _problem_ you are having with it. This is a topic that has been asked about numerous times before, so surely you have found something to try? Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to show us what you did so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create .htaccess file in your base folder(example: public_html)
then write below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?department/(\w+\.html)/?$ /department.php/$1 [END,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward and there are many many examples here on SO that you could have looked at to find your solution yourself.

Here is a starting point, you still may have to tweak it for your usage:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?department/(\w+\.html)/?$ /department.php/$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` redirection method

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?department/(\w+\.html)/?$ /department.php/$1 [END,QSA]
```